# Arrowheads every two points in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I have a file data.dat with the following lines:

```
-1.200000     0.000000
-1.200000    -0.728000
-0.728000    -0.728000
-0.728000     0.614172
 0.614172     0.614172
 0.614172     1.231670
```

which stores a set of points with `x` and `y` coordinates. I subsequently want to plot this list of points with arrowheads every two points (or every point, that would be fine as well) as follows (but with arrowheads instead of mark=*):

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[mark=*,mark indices={2,4,...,8}] plot file {data.dat};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It looks like there is not mark which looks like arrowhead: would a better solution be the use of a `foreach` loop that reads in the data file?

Comment: What would be the direction of the arrow heads? Following the path? With the decorations library you can try something like `\draw[decoration={markings,mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.728cm with {\arrow{stealth}}},postaction={decorate}] plot file {data.dat};`

Comment: yes, the direction would be following the path. This is probably why `mark=` is not an option. I thought about the decoration approach but the steps are not of equal size.

Comment: Well they are equally distant in terms path length but not vertically.

Comment: A solution would be to prepare a script that writes the proper `tikz` code for each segment as follows: `\draw[->](point A) -- (point B);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a suggestion that uses Lua to write multiple `\draw`s, and therefore has to be compiled with `lualatex`. I borrowed the file reading code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038236/store-in-2d-array-the-contents-of-file-lua

There is a problem with the corners between the arrows because the line is drawn as separate paths, so they're not joined properly. For this specific case, a hack would be to add `[shorten >=-0.5\\pgflinewidth]` to the `draw` in the `else` clause.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,luacode,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
-1.200000     0.000000
-1.200000    -0.728000
-0.728000    -0.728000
-0.728000     0.614172
 0.614172     0.614172
 0.614172     1.231670
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{luacode}
local mt = {}          -- create the matrix
for line in io.lines'data.dat' do
  local new_row = {}
  for n in line:gmatch'%S+' do
     table.insert(new_row, tonumber(n))
  end
  if #new_row > 0 then
     table.insert(mt, new_row)
  end
endrows = \#mt
for i=1,endrows-1 do
    if i % 2 == 1 then
    tex.sprint("\\draw [-latex] (", mt[i][1], ",",  mt[i][2] , ") -- (", mt[i+1][1], ",",  mt[i+1][2], ");")
    else
    tex.sprint("\\draw (", mt[i][1], ",",  mt[i][2] , ") -- (", mt[i+1][1], ",",  mt[i+1][2], ");")
    end
    end
end
\end{luacode}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[mark=*,mark indices={2,4,...,8}] plot file {data.dat};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```